# i18n and Java validation annotation messages

Tags: java, validation, internationalization, annotations

I've got the following annotation:

```
@NotEmpty
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = SupportedVideoUrlValidator.class)
public @interface SupportedVideoUrl {
    String message() default "{cast.submission.error.video}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    String value() default "";
}
```

It works OK except the i18n part. The post-validation error message is displayed as is. 
I do not know how to handle this...

If you have any ideas, thanks in advance for your help!

Rolf

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using [JSR-303](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303) annontations, put a file `ValidationMessages.properties` at the root of your classpath containing:

```
cast.submission.error.video=Video URL is not supported.
```

this file is loaded as a [ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) so if you need message for a different language add the language suffix to the file (eg `ValidationMessages_de.properties` for german translations).